# Problems with do while implementation

Tags: fortran

I am having problems with a do while implementation for a sine taylor series.  Editing the do loop to do bb = 1, 10 , 2 gives an expected result well within the margin of error, however when running the desired implementation of the do loop (do while(abs(sineseries) - accuracy > 0), will always give an answer equal to 1.  So I have narrowed the possibilities  down to the do while loop implementation being faulty.

```
program taylor
 implicit none
 real :: x
 real :: sineseries, nfactsine
 real, parameter :: accuracy = 1.e-10
 integer :: signum, bb

 nfactsine = 1
 signum = 1
 write(*,*) "Write your input value"
 read(*,*) x
 sineseries = 0

  do while(abs(sineseries) - accuracy > 0)
    sineseries = sineseries + (signum*x**bb)/nfactsine
    nfactsine = nfactsine*(bb+1)*(bb+2)
    signum = -signum

  end do
  write(*,*) sineseries, sin(x)
end program taylor
```

Comment: `do while loop implementation being faulty`: if you mean that the compiler is at fault here I doubt it. Consider franscescalus' reply and the fact that your criterion for the loop termination `abs(sineseries) - accuracy > 0` is `.false.` when entering the loop! Use the increment instead: `abs((signum*x**bb)/nfactsine) - accuracy > 0`.

Answer (score 1):

The two types of loops are not doing the same thing.

In the loop

```
do bb=1, 10, 2
  ...
end do
```

you have loop control with variable `bb`.  This variable takes the values `1`, `3`, ..., `9` at iterations as the loop proceeds.

The `do while` does not have this control: you must replicate the increment of `bb` manually:

```
bb=1
do while (...)
  ...
  bb=bb+2
end do
```

---

As Pierre de Buyl commented, you also have an error in the termination condition for the indefinite iteration count.  The condition initially evaluates as false, so the loop body isn't executed even once.